# How to add multiple lines using ggplot given two vectors of their coefficients without using for loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Using for loop is significantly slower and just doesn't seems right. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could use some other method with geom_abline(intercept, slope).
The variable Coeff is a list contains four data frames of all the parameters, each data frame have 1001 rows (the first one is useless).

```
p <- qplot(x,y,data = data,color = I("blue"))
for (i in 1:1000){
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept = Coeff[[1]]$Intercept[i+1], slope = Coeff[[1]]$X[i+1],alpha = 0.1,size = 0.1, colour = "red")
}
for (i in 1:1000){
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept = Coeff[[3]]$Intercept[i+1], slope = Coeff[[3]]$X[i+1],alpha = 0.1,size = 0.1, colour = "yellow")
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell from your question what you are talking about at all. You should consider adding a working code example that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass vectors to `slope` and `intercept`

```
g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=-10:10, y=-10:10), aes(x, y))+geom_point()
my_coefs <- data.frame(slope=-5:5, intercept=-5:5)

g + geom_abline(data=my_coefs, aes(slope=slope, intercept=intercept))
```

Comment: +1 I was literally just about click "Post Your Answer".

Comment: @WangWeinan My pleasure. If I've answered your question, please mark it as such and click the checkbox up in the corner.

Comment: What about I want to draw quadratic functions with three parameters? I guess I have to use stat_function instead, can I still pass vectors as parameters? @Justin

Comment: Sounds about right. I've got no idea, but you're welcome to experiment!